# Generate HREF link depending on value in MySQL table row

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP, 
my question is; how can I make the href generate itself based on the value of 
    $row['category']?
If anything is unclear, please let me know.

```
<?php
    echo "<div class=News>";
$q = "SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY newsno DESC";
$r = mysqli_query($mysqli, "$q");
if($r)
{

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    echo "<form action=index.php method=post>";
    echo "<div class=Container>";
    echo "<div class=Newsheader>";
    echo "<h7>";
    echo $row['newstopic'];
    echo "</h7>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<a href=image.php?newsno=".$row['newsno']." data-lightbox=roadtrip><img src=image.php?newsno=".$row['newsno']." width=180 height=180/></a>";
    echo "<div class=tb>";
    echo nl2br(substr ($row['newsinfo'], 0, 50));
    echo "<a href='This/Is/My/problem"."'> ...Read more</a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class=newsfooter>";
    echo 'Category: ' . $row['category']; 
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</br>";
    echo "</br>";
    echo "</form>";
}
echo "</div>";

}

else
{
echo mysqli_error();
}

?>
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? Can you explain it with an example.

Comment: On my php page where i create these news I have 5 radio buttons which represents; Energy, Disposal etc. Whatever option I choose is then sent to my MySQL db table through a storeinfo.php file. In the code above I retrieve everything from the db, where i've added the  echo 'Category: ' . $row['category']; description at the end of the file. 

I want to make the echo "<a href='GenerateItself"."'> ...Read more</a>"; generate the href based on what value the $row['category'] has in the database table. 

I don't know if u understood more of this. ><

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible from mysql.You have to do it with php(if else conditions )

Comment: When I for instance make a new one, with the category "Energy" I want the href to change to "Energy.php".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to make dynamic url according to category than you need to put

```
echo '<a href="https://www.vg.no/'.$row['category'].'"> ...Read more</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, It was not ment to have the "https://www.vg.no/" link in the href, my bad. This wont work due to the $row['category'] is not leading to any pages. My pages are for instance, energy.php, disposal.php

Comment: you need to give your path there.. it will look like echo '<a href="https://www.whatever.no/energry.php?name='.$row['category'].'"> ...Read more</a>';

//whaever the value of $row['category'] will make it dynamic